# How do I append an input string into a dictionary key int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make the following code prompt for an answer and than add that answer into the dictionary  titled poll. I'm trying the append command which is usually used for list but it doesn't just work for a dictionary.

At the moment I neither managed to update the key values (my intended goal) or even managed to just add a new item to the dictionary (non intended).

```
poll = {
    'cat': 0,
    'dog': 0,
    'both': 0,
    'none': 0,
    }

prompt = "Are you a cat owner, dog owner, both, or none? "
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' to stop this loop \n"
message = ""
while message != "quit":
    message = input(prompt)
    poll[message].append(value)
    if message != "quit":
        print("Your answer was submitted! \n")

print("Poll results:\n", poll)
```

Comment: Where does `value` come from? Are you trying to increment the count?

Comment: are you trying to store multiple responses to your poll? or just sum the number of responses per category?

Comment: You should at least add some input validation or any non-standard answer would cause it to fail even if the dictionary logic is fixed.

Comment: @Mark Meyer. value was a placeholder from when I was trying something from another example with no luck. The code example there didn't declare "value" either so I thought it might mean something and my IDE wasn't telling me it was an error.

Comment: @Stefano Gallotti. Just store the sum of the number of responses

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new key-value pair to the dictionary, instead of appending you can do the following, although I do not see a variable `value` in your code. It will also update the value of existing key if entered again because dictionary cannot have duplicate keys

```
poll[message] = value
```

Assuming you take care of the variable `value`, the code will look like

As pointed out by David Buck, you need to move the `poll[message] = value` part inside the `if` statement

```
while message != "quit":
    message = input(prompt)
    if message != "quit":
        poll[message] = value
        print("Your answer was submitted! \n")

print("Poll results:\n", poll)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be mistaking something. You don't have any list nor a variable called `value`. If you are trying to count the number of people with pets you may use `poll[message] += 1`.

E.g:

```
poll = {
    'cat': 0,
    'dog': 0,
    'both': 0,
    'none': 0,
    }

poll['cat'] += 1     # poll['cat'] = poll['cat'] + 1
poll['cat'] += 1     # poll['cat'] = poll['cat'] + 1
poll['dog'] += 1     # poll['dog'] = poll['dog'] + 1

print(poll)
# {'cat': 2, 'dog': 1, 'both': 0, 'none': 0}
```

In addition, you should change the condition of the `while` and the order of the `if` statement:

```
poll = {
    'cat': 0,
    'dog': 0,
    'both': 0,
    'none': 0,
    }

prompt = "Are you a cat owner, dog owner, both, or none? "
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' to stop this loop \n"
message = ""
while True:
    message = input(prompt)
    if message != "quit":
        print("Your answer was submitted! \n")
    else:
        break
    poll[message] += 1


print("Poll results:\n", poll)
```

Test:

```
Are you a cat owner, dog owner, both, or none? 
Enter 'quit' to stop this loop 
>>> cat
Your answer was submitted! 

Are you a cat owner, dog owner, both, or none? 
Enter 'quit' to stop this loop 
>>> cat
Your answer was submitted! 

Are you a cat owner, dog owner, both, or none? 
Enter 'quit' to stop this loop 
>>> dog
Your answer was submitted! 

Are you a cat owner, dog owner, both, or none? 
Enter 'quit' to stop this loop 
>>> quit
Poll results:
 {'cat': 2, 'dog': 1, 'both': 0, 'none': 0}
```

Obviously, there are a lot more things you can do, like using `poll.get(key, default)` to add values, e.: `poll[message] = poll.get(message, 0) + 1`, so even if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary it doesn't crash the script, instead, it makes a new key. Or before adding the value to the dictionary check `if message in poll.keys(): poll[message] += 1` so the script only accepts `cat`, `dog`, `both` or `none` but not `car` or `bird`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just update the value of the dictionary based on the vote. Here's an example for me entering 'dog':

Initial Dictionary:

```
poll = {
    'cat': 0,
    'dog': 0,
    'both': 0,
    'none': 0,
    }
```

My response:

```
my_response = 'dog'
```

Update the 'dog' key:

```
poll[my_response] += 1
```

Output:

```
{'cat': 0, 'dog': 1, 'both': 0, 'none': 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

this need to work:

```
poll = {
    'cat': 0,
    'dog': 0,
    'both': 0,
    'none': 0,
    }

prompt = "Are you a cat owner, dog owner, both, or none? "
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' to stop this loop \n"
message = ""
while message != "quit":
    message = input(prompt)
    if message in list(poll):
        pass
    else:
        #else it will give a error that it isn't a key
        continue
    num = poll[message]
    num += 1
    poll[message] = num
    if message != "quit":
        print("Your answer was submitted! \n")

print("Poll results:\n", poll)
```

Comment: now i have the variable num and not the variable value. this need to work well